# Google Calendar - XML feed not correct

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am getting a Google Calendar XML Feed with the following code.

My problem is I have 'singleevents=true' set in the URL yet when I actually look at the feed it is showing 24 entries and only one of these is unique, whereas the rest are all a repeat of one event.

In my calendar I have 1 single event and 6 events which each recur weekly.

```
$api = new clApi('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/' . $calendarID .'/public/full?singleevents=true&amp;min-start=' . $now . '&amp;max-start=' .$next_week);

    if ($feed = $api->parse()) {            
        foreach($feed->get('entry') as $entry) {
.....
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the syntax for the parameter backwards. According to the documentation at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/reference#Parameters : *"Valid values are true (expand recurring events) or false (leave recurring events represented as single events). Default is false."*

Comment: Personally not the best wording I've ever seen. I would have thought 'leave as single event' Would mean the single event which the recursion comes from i.e. the original, and expanding would make each occurrence singular?